# Slim Framework /public folder redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I am using Slim Framework v3. I've set up API and its working smoothly if I access http://localhost:8080/slimapp/public

I have default directory structure. My Sample API endpoint is http://localhost:8080/slimapp/public/cards which returns JSON response of my cards

How Could I change the **public** folder to the domain, So I would be able to access my cards endpoint with http://localhost:8080/slimapp/cards?

Comment: Some code might help... and an example of your directory structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply rewrite the requests with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/slimapp/public
RewriteRule ^slimapp/(.*)$ /slimapp/public/$1 [L]
```

This will serve the appropriate `public` folder, without redirecting the client. The `RewriteCond` is needed to avoid a redirect loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can also edit Slim's default .htaccess file as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Note: .htaccess file must be located in server root