# Redirect URL from root to Public folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, uri, slim-3

I have a SLIM project I have set up for a RESTful webs service. My project structure is as below:

```
-MyProject
   -app
   -logs
   -public
     -index.php
     -.htaccess
   -vendor
   -composer.json
   -composer.lock
```

So right now to access my routes I would need something like `https://myuri/MyProject/public/endpoint`

I want to remove the public directory from the url so my request looks more like `https://myuri/MyProject/endpoint`

I have tried adding an `.htaccess` to my root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I just get page not found. What is the best way to remove the public directory from the url?

Comment: take index.php and .htaccess file outside of public folder and remove public from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [R=301,L]` so it should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I tried doing that but I keep getting redirected to `/MyProject/public/` now.

Comment: check this post this will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505870/slim-framework-public-folder-redirect

OR 
You can try this 
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`