# Slim Framework remove public folder in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

There is a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505870/slim-framework-public-folder-redirect), but I still need to include the `public` folder in my URL.

Current URL: `https://my-domain.com/api/public/pins`

What I want: `https://my-domain.com/api/pins`

This is my project structure

[image]

As you can see, I have 2 .htaccess files, where and what should I write a .htaccess script to redirect the `public` folder?

`.htaccess` in `public` folder

```
# Redirect to front controller
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

`.htaccess` in `root` folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example to make an "internal redirect" to the public directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

The `.htaccess` in the `public/` directory could contain this content:

```
# Redirect to front controller
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

In Slim 4: Make sure to set the correct Slim basePath.

```php
$app->setBasePath('/api');
```

See documentation: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html#apache-configuration

In Slim 3: Patch the Slim Environment as follows.

```php
$container['environment'] = function () {
    $scriptName = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $_SERVER['REAL_SCRIPT_NAME'] = $scriptName;
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = dirname(dirname($scriptName)) . '/' . basename($scriptName);

    return new Slim\Http\Environment($_SERVER);
};
```

[Example](https://github.com/odan/prisma/blob/master/config/container.php#L45-L51)

Comment: But it's still not working. I will update the question instead

Comment: I also updated my answer.

Comment: I use slim 3 :(

Comment: Can you upgrade to Slim 4? I updated my answer for Slim 3.

Comment: No, I don't want to upgrade to Slim 4. It's finally working, thank you :)